How to conditionally extract type from mp_list and form a new list in c++ TMP?
I am practicing C++ template metaprogramming (TMP) using boost::mp11 library. What I want to achieve is like this:
// first, some types that I plan to use
template< typename tag, uint32_t _data >
struct DType
{
  using typeTag = tag;
  uint32_t payload = _data;
};

template< typename tag >
struct AType
{
  using typeTag = tag;
  int32_t  process () { return 0; };
};

template< typename tag >
struct VType
{
  using typeTag = tag;
  bool  verify() { return true; };
};

// define a bunch of type tags
using inputA = mp_int< 0 >;
using inputB = mp_int< 1 >;
using ProcA = mp_int< 2 >;
using ProcB = mp_int< 3 >;
using VrfyA = mp_int< 4 >;

// then all the possible types stores in a list
using TypePool = mp_list< DType<inputA, 0>, DType<inputB, 1>, DType<inputB, 2>, 
                          AType< ProcA >, AType< ProcB >, 
                          VType< VrfyA > >;

// provide a filter list
using filter = mp_list< inputB, ProcA, VrfyA >;

// so far so good, what I want is to create a bunch of mp_lists according to
// the filter from the TypePool; ideally I want something like following:

// just to show what's the final result looks like
using list1 = mp_list< DType< inputB, 1 >, AType< ProcA >, VType< VrfyA > >; 
using list2 = mp_list< DType< inputB, 2 >, AType< ProcA >, VType< VrfyA > >; 

Basically, I select type out of TypePool according to the tags listed in the
filter. And then create new lists according to the order defined in the filter.
All the lists are variable in length. Any suggestion how to do this?

It is possible to implement a custom type trait, filtered_list, whose type defines a list that contains the first types in the source list T filtered according to the tags in the filter list U. In particular, for each tag in the filter list, it is added the first type in the source list whose first template parameter is the same as the above tag.
The only one pre-condition involves that, for each tag, there be the corresponding type in the source list, otherwise the program is ill-formed.
To make the implementation easier, it is exploited a helper type trait, extract, whose type, provided a certain tag, defines the corresponding first type in the source list. In this way, it is sufficient to iteratively specialize the helper for all types in the filter list.
Example:
namespace detail {
    template <typename, typename...>
    struct extract
    {};
    
    template <typename T, typename U, typename ...Us>
    struct extract<T, U, Us...>
     : extract<T, Us...>
    {};
    
    template <typename T, template <typename, auto...> typename U, auto ...Ns, typename ...Us>
    struct extract<T, U<T, Ns...>, Us...>
    { using type = U<T, Ns...>; };
    
    template <typename, typename>
    struct filtered_list
    {};
    
    template <template <typename...> typename T, typename ...Us, typename ...Vs>
    struct filtered_list<T<Us...>, T<Vs...>>
    { using type = T<typename extract<Vs, Us...>::type...>; };
}

template <typename T, typename U>
struct filtered_list
 : detail::filtered_list<T, U>
{};

template <typename T, typename U>
using filtered_list_t = typename filtered_list<T, U>::type;

